# Storm to read message from RabbitMq using Spring AMQP

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, apache-storm, spring-rabbit

I want to consume the messages in my Storm Spout from a rabbitMq Queue.

Now , we are using Spring AMQP to send and receive messages from RabbitMq asynchronously.

Spring AMQP provides mechanism(either creating a listener or using annotation @RabbitListner)  to read message from the queue .

The problem is I can have a Listener to read the message from the Queue. But how do I send this message to my Storm Spout which is running on storm cluster ?

The topology will start a cluster, but in my nextTuple() method of my spout , I need to read message from this Queue. Can Spring AMQP be used here ?

I have a listener configured to read message from the queue:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "queueName")
public void processMessage(QueueMessage message) {

}
```

How can the above message received at the listener be sent to my spout running on a cluster .

Alternatively , how can a spout's nextTuple() method have this method inside it ? Is it possible

I am using Java as a language here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read messages on-demand (rather than being message-driven) by using one of the `RabbitTemplate` `receive` or `receiveAndConvert` methods.

By default, they will return null if there is no message in the queue.

**EDIT**:

If you set the `receiveTimeout` (available in version 1.5 or above), the receive methods will block for that time (it uses an async consumer internally and does not poll).

But it's still not as efficient as the listener because a new consumer is created for each method; to use a listener you would need to use some internal blocking mechanism in `nextTuple()` (e.g. a `BlockingQueue`) to wait for messages.

Comment: Thanks for replying Gary .I have 2 questions : 1) I believe recieve or recieveAndConvert continuosly poll the queue to check if some message is there . How much is the polling time ? I am using Apache Storm here for real time processing and expectation is message should be delivered as soon as it is available in the queue  . Not sure if polling is the right approach since we are concerned about real time .Also , there may be periods when there will be no message in the queue . Will using receive not hamper performance ?

Comment: If you set the `receiveTimeout` (available in version 1.5 or above), the receive methods will block for that time (it uses an async consumer internally and does not poll).

Comment: I couldnt understand what you meant when you say "a new consumer is created for each method" . If possible , can you elaborate a bit on this sentence ?

Comment: When using a blocking receive, the template creates a new async consumer; waits for a message, then cancels the consumer. The listener container uses a long-lived consumer so it's more efficient.

Comment: Thanks Gary , also under the hood does listener continuously blocks for receiving the message?

Comment: Yes; it blocks waiting for an async delivery from rabbitmq.